# Old questions are very very old

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

Super old Super old Super old Super old Super old Super old Super old Super old

Comment: Have you at least *considered* watching YT and reading articles on the internet about the subject?

Comment: You can use apache or ngnix to serve up plain vanilla html without node. There are lots of other webservers you could use but those two are the most popular. nginx is newer and generally considered faster for plain html.

Comment: Questions here should indicate and show that you've at least done basic research on the topic and then you can ask a specific question.

Answer (score 1):

If you've done lots of front end where the folder and file just show up where it should online, and lots of back end that's just API work, then do that.

Have NGINX or Apache serve your static files, then have your JS client code call the API you write in Node.  A lot of apps do things this way, and it's very clean.